# Using multiple "matches" statements in Drools-Guvnor

Tags: drools, business-rules, drools-guvnor

I am creating rules through the drools-guvnor. I have imported my POJO model and everything is set up correctly (I have done tests) but I cant seems to figure out how to get the "matches" operator working correctly. This is what I have so far(source code):

```
rule "invilidSms"
dialect "mvel"
    when
        invalidSms : Policy( SMS_Area_Code matches "[0-9]{4,}" || matches "^[0-9]{0,2}" || matches "[0-9\\D]+" , SMS_TelNumber matches "[0-9]{4,}" || matches "^[0-9]{0,2}" || matches "[0-9\\D]+" , SMS_nixieindicator == "Y" || == "y" )
    then
        invalidSms.setSms( ""Invalid area code"" );
end
```

Could anyone give me any tips on using multiple regex checks in drools-guvnor or some way of getting this to work. It seems as though their forum is really stale. Most of the answers I could find on there haven't been answered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to pipe the regular expressions only. 
something like:

```
rule "invilidSms"
dialect "mvel"
when
    invalidSms : Policy( SMS_Area_Code matches "[0-9]{4,}|^[0-9]{0,2}|[0-9\\D]+" , SMS_TelNumber matches "[0-9]{4,}|^[0-9]{0,2}|[0-9\\D]+" , SMS_nixieindicator matches "[Yy]"
then
    invalidSms.setSms( ""Invalid area code"" );
end
```

Comment: How would I do this through the gui though? It seems as if the gui creates them incorrectly. I am not creating technical rules, thats the problem

Comment: what version you are using? I am on 5.3.1.Final and its working inside my business rule. You should have 3 condition columns and 1 action column. what also works is exporting the *.gdst file from guvnor, edit in texteditor and save it back. see this: [Accessing Guvnor as a Filesystem (WebDAV) ](http://blog.athico.com/2008/05/accessing-guvnor-as-filesystem-webdav.html)

Comment: @MethodMan, could you please tell us how you solved the problem?

Comment: Hi metar, I would suggest you either upgrade your version of drools or create a `regex` statement that can deal with all of the rules at once. That is how we managed to solve it.